# VictoryLine apply LinearGradient

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I'm using Victory React Native library with line chart but i'm not able to add LinearGradient to stroke of Path.

Can someone help me?

```
<Svg style={styles.container}>
  <Defs>
        <LinearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <Stop offset="0%"   stopColor="green"/>
          <Stop offset="100%" stopColor="red"/>
        </LinearGradient>
      </Defs>
      <VictoryLine
        animate={{
          onLoad: { duration: 3000 }
        }}
        height={200}
        width={500}
        style={{
          data: {
            stroke: 'purple',
            strokeWidth: 3
          }
        }}
        interpolation="natural"
        data={sampleData}
      />
    </Svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stroke: 'url(#linear)'
```

It should work

Comment: You would also need to add the standalone prop to false